# how to configure grafana with oauth (private ADFS)

Tags: oauth, adfs, grafana

I would make an o.auth connection with an ADFS server. I followed the doc http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/#auth-generic-oauth.

Conf:

```
[auth.generic_oauth]
enabled = true
client_id = ID
client_secret = TOKEN
scopes = openid
auth_url = https://GO.tld/adfs/oauth2/authorize
token_url = https://GO.tld/adfs/oauth2/token
api_url = https://GO.tld/adfs/userinfo
allowed_domains = GO.tld
allow_sign_up = true
```

Log

```
lvl=dbug msg="HTTP GET https://GO.tld/adfs/userinfo: 200 OK {\"sub\":\"165az5d55s5sa56a5z1ds22tr6h5g5g6za6a6z55z5s=\"}"
lvl=dbug msg="HTTP GET https://GO.tld/adfs/userinfo/emails: 200 OK {\"sub\":\"165az5d55s5sa56a5z1ds22tr6h5g5g6za6a6z55z5s=\"}"
lvl=dbug msg="OAuthLogin got user info" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= userInfo="&{Name: Email: Login: Company: Role:}"
lvl=info msg="Login provider didn't return an email address" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname=
lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/login/generic_oauth status=302 remote_addr=IP time_ms=26 size=29 referer=https://grafana.tld:3000/login
```

Answer (score 0):

The logs show that the `https://GO.tld/adfs/userinfo` is returning `{"sub":"165az5d55s5sa56a5z1ds22tr6h5g5g6za6a6z55z5s="}`, where grafana expects a json document including fields like `name`, `login`, `username`, `email`.  I found a few posts referencing that URL as returning a full userinfo, so it's possible you may need to update the `scopes` setting to something like `openid userinfo` to have it return more fields rather than just `sub`.

As far as I can make out, the access token itself should be a JWT token that includes the user info, so in theory it should be possible to either update the generic oauth module to be able to decode that and use it, or make a separate module for ADFS.  Right now though Grafana doesn't decode it, and just treats it as an opaque value.

Finally, if there is another API endpoint Grafana can call to get a json representation of the user, then you may be able to set the `api_url` to that and things would work.